# Big image drawn on small canvas become blurrier

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

In my project i have a canvas (200*150) and i want to draw an image of size (800*600) . The result is that image become bluer (not smooth and clear) , but if we put that image on *img* tag it look well. So how can we deal with this? thanks.

```
<img src="http://www.drivingkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/preschool-math-game-for-kids-math-racing-equatations.jpg"
width="200" heigh="150" />
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var context = document.getElementById("my_canvas").getContext("2d");
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = "http://www.drivingkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/preschool-math-game-for-kids-math-racing-equatations.jpg";
        image.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); //dx-30, GY-28, GW+50, GH+35
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you add the code or better make a fiddle for that canvas?

Comment: "There is coming this sound from my engine.." :-) As rps, you need to give us a little more to look at, preferably as a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net). You should also include code in your post that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Maybe resize the image to 200x150 on the server side or in your image editor.  IMHO, while the canvas resized image is slightly pixelated versus the img, it's not all that noticeable at that size. (Much more noticeable pixelation at 400x300 for example.)

Answer (score 3):

## Cause

Browsers can prioritize quality or performance depending on the current scenario.

For images quality is typically prioritized over performance for most pages. But for canvas performance is not as good as with for instance direct browser rendering and CSS so the interpolation with canvas may have performance prioritized before quality. Depending on browser implementation.

## Solution

Luckily there is a way to work around this by sort of splitting the burden with the resizing and interpolation by doing it in two (or more) steps, or one intermediate step if you like.

The intermediate step will first scale the image 50% to an off-screen canvas. Then use that canvas to draw to the final size. For larger images more steps will perhaps be needed.

The time spent in sum is about the same due to the sum of the operations to get the new sizes (more simply put: less to interpolate with intermediate step x2, versus more to interpolate x1) so you won't notice much performance reduction.

But most importantly: the result will be better than with just a single step.

## Implementation

This is how you can implement an intermediate step:

```
image.onload = function () {

     /// create an extra step for re-sizing image
     var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
         tmpContext = c.getContext('2d');

     /// set this canvas to 50% of image
     tmpCanvas.width = image.width * 0.5;
     tmpCanvas.height = image.height * 0.5;

     /// draw image step 1
     tmpContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width * 0.5, image.height * 0.5);

     /// draw image step 2
     context.drawImage(tmpCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

## Demo (proof-of-concept)

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/DgJk5/)**

The result will be:

[image: snapshot of result]
<sup>Left image: IMG element. Right image: canvas two steps (rendered in Firefox)</sup>

As you can see there is now no noticeable difference between image and canvas element.

Comment: @PonSomean Glad I could help! Please consider to accept the answer as well (this will close the question and we who answer get some kudos).